# cannot program address in sandbox interface because it conflicts with existing route

Tags: docker-compose

I was adding custom networks for my containers in my docker-compose file. But I came across this error when running `docker-compose up`

I just added:

```yaml
networks:
  - mumble
```

and that caused `docker-compose up` to make this error show up:

> +] Running 1/2
> ⠿ Container murmur       Started                                                              > 1.6s
> ⠿ Container botamusique  Starting                                                           > 1.4s
>
> Error response from daemon: failed to add interface veth60b7c6b to sandbox: error setting interface "veth60b7c6b" IP to 172.18.0.3/16: cannot program address 172.18.0.3/16 in sandbox interface because it conflicts with existing route {Ifindex: 38 Dst: 172.18.0.0/16 Src: 172.18.0.1 Gw:  Flags: [] Table: 254}

Answer (score 7):

This is pretty simple but the error message doesn't really make it easier.

This error will happen if you happen to have

```yaml
network_mode: host
```

and

```yaml
networks:
 - somenetwork
```

at once in the same .yaml file, which naturally conflicts with eachother

Just remove `network_mode: host` and keep `networks:` and it'll work fine